# ag-grid rendering component using cellRendererFramework throws error

Tags: angular, gridview, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to render a component with ag-grid but get this error:

> core.js:15713 ERROR Error: No component factory found for
>   squareRenderer. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
>       at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:9875)

**table.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [SquareRenderer, ...containers, ...components],
    imports: [
    ...
        AgGridModule.withComponents([SquareRenderer]),
        ...
    ],
    entryComponents: [SquareRenderer],
    exports: [],
    providers: []
})
export class TableModule {}
```

**table-component.ts**

```
columnDefs = [
{
    headerName: '',
    children: [
      {
        headerName: 'Farm/Field',
        field: 'farm',
        width: 183,
        lockPosition: true,
        cellRendererFramework: 'squareRenderer'
        },
        ...
]
frameworkComponents = {
  squareRenderer: SquareRenderer
  };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ag-grid-angular
        #agGrid
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
        class="ag-theme-balham"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
        [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
        [cacheBlockSize]="cacheBlockSize"
        [infiniteInitialRowCount]="infiniteInitialRowCount"
        [rowModelType]="'infinite'"
        [maxBlocksInCache]="maxBlocksInCache"
        [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
        >
      </ag-grid-angular>
```

Why do I get this message? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: everything looks ok, can you create stackblitz with your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Angular modules and add this to the imports

```
AgGridModule.withComponents([
  SquareRenderer
]),
```

and import

```
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
```